Is my setup for a 5V motor project faulty?
I'm trying to get a motor (5V nailbrush, no name, no specifications whatsoever) to spin for a set time and pause for a set time using a PIC10F200 microcontroller in conjunction with a 2N2222 NPN transistor and 1N4007 diode flywheel, with the Arduino Uno as the power supply provider.
I need an explination on how I'd have to connect an alternative transistor (PNP 2N3906 H331) since I plan to make more of the similar project but I can't get any NPNs any time soon. Programing the microcontroller is done via PicKit5, the coding is done in MPLAB x IDE(6.20) XC8 Compiler.
Diagram:

Code:
#pragma config MCLRE = OFF      // Master Clear Enable (GP3/MCLR pin fuction is digital I/O, MCLR internally tied to VDD)

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        TRISGPIO = 0b00000000;
        __delay_ms(1500);
        GPIObits.GP1 = 1;
        __delay_ms(1500);
        GPIObits.GP1 = 0;
    }
}

I'm not the brightest on electronics oron physics, but from what I can add, the transistor heats up (as a side note I have wiggled around the wires brainlessly, the only time the motor worked without load was once and it was locked in continuous spin. I have checked the integrity of the transistor with a multimeter and it is fine.)
I do have a radiator to "glue" to the transistor but I'd like to know if the setup is faulty in components and have a replacement instead (I don't want to burn down the house.)

I have no enemies - Hi, There are some problems with the question and what's been happening: (a) The schematic given has an NPN transistor and the 1st answer explains the problems in that schematic. (b) Your question also asks how you would use a PNP transistor instead (since you explain you can't get more NPN transistors). That really should be a separate question (and will probably be a duplicate, as similar questions have been asked here before). (c) Now you've significantly added to the question, with a new breadboard layout that wasn't included originally with a PNP transistor.

(continued) This is turning it into a "chameleon question" with no clear end (since the original question is changing). Questions with moving goalposts don't fit with Stack Exchange's approach of having one, clear question per topic. || Therefore I have removed the non-working breadboard with PNP transistor from your question. You can ask that separately, but please also include the schematic of what you're trying to do, relevant voltage measurements, and explain your troubleshooting so far. It's asking too much to expect people to reverse-engineer wiring from a breadboard taken at an angle.

@SamGibson ok thanks

You have the transistor "upside down."  It should be like this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

The arrow in the transistor symbol points towards ground.  In your circuit, it points to 5V.
The transistor is between the motor and ground.  In your circuit, you have the transistor between 5V and the motor.
The diode should be connected so that it does not normally conduct.  A 1N4007 is probably not fast enough to really catch the spikes.  I'd use something like a UF4007.
Add a capacitor across the motor to reduce electrical noise.


I can't find a 200nF capacitor, I only have ~1uF up to 220uF, I'd have to connect like 5x1uF in series. Would it be ideal?

The exact value of the capacitor doesn't matter.  There's not enough information about the motor to do any kind of estimate.  100nF is a standard value.  If you use 200 nF, that's fine.  If you have to use 47nF, that's fine, too.  1µF is kind of on the high side.

The setup doesn't work for me after I followed your diagram.
